# Difference between the MFCC feature used in speaker recognition and speech recognition?

Tags: speech-recognition, voice-recognition, mfcc

I have a conceptual problem.

I know what is a MFCC. But I am not able to find the difference between the mfcc feature vector for speaker recognition and speech recognition i.e. which part of the mfcc feature is used as differentiating factor between two?
And Also how we can differentiate two speakers on the basis of mfcc vector?

Answer (score 0):

The features are very similar. What makes a difference is the number of coefficients, window size, normalization ... etc. Have a look at [this thread](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10826/difference-between-mfcc-of-speech-and-speaker-recognition).

Using mfcc features you can differeniate speakers in several ways. Two of the most famous techniques are:

- **GMM/UBM technique**: where you create a GMM for each speaker and another GMM as a background model, then you score input utterances.
- **i-vector technique**: It's sort of a post processing on the mfcc to generate a new vector representing the speaker acoustic model. This technique is used in [Microsoft Speaker Recognition Service](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/speaker-recognition-api), and [here's a description](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/machinelearning/2015/12/14/now-available-speaker-video-apis-from-microsoft-project-oxford/) of how it works.